# Amstrad CPC 464 tape deck loads, but makes grinding scratching noise

Tags: hardware, cpc464

I'm concerned about an Amstrad CPC 464 tape deck, which loads, but makes grinding scratching noise while rewinding, fast-forwarding and play.

Sometimes it does load silently, but after a subsequent rewind the scratching noise returns.

It is very loud.

I have discontinued use while I figure out a solution.

Please help me.

Comment: Is the sound coming from the speaker connected to the audio output or from the actual deck?

Comment: sounds like mechanical problem did you check the motor ribbon? maybe it is partially out of its slot or there is some dirt near the wheels (or even scraped tape) May be Hearing the sound would tell us more can you make a record of it?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that parts of the drive mechanism are worn, out of adjustment, or need lubricating.  Tape cassette decks are all very similar to each other in principle, so I suggest looking for a generic repair guide.  Even some aspects of VCR repair guides are likely to be relevant.